# Solving large system of equations with 4 unknowns

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a dataset including the distance and bearing to ~1800 fused radar contacts as well as the actual distance and bearing to those contacts, and I need to develop a correction equation to get the perceived values to be as close to the actual values as possible.

There seems to be a trend in the error when visualizing, so it seems to me that there should be a somewhat simple equation to correct it.

This is the form of the ~1800 equations:

actual_distance = perceived_distance + X(percieved_bearing) + Y(speed_over_ground) + Z(course_over_ground) + A(heading)

What is the best way to solve for X, Y, Z, and A?

Also, I'm not convinced that all of these factors are necessary, so I'm completely willing to leave out one or two of the factors.

From the little linear algebra I understand, I've attempted something like this with no luck:

Ax = b  -->  x = b/A via numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)

where A is the 4 x ~1800 matrix and b is the 1 x ~1800 matrix

Is this on the right track?

To be clear, I'm expecting to generate coefficeints for an equation that will correct percieved distance to a contact so that it is as close as possible to the actual distance to contact.

I am also totally willing to abandon this method if there is abetter one.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I have also thought about breaking up the matrices to a bunch of 4x4 and 1x4, solving, and taking the average of the solutions. Is that reasonable? 

I don't need mathematical perfection, just to correct the values as much as posssible.

Comment: I'd be a bit worried about the bearings. As far as the sums go, 359.9 will be very different from 0.1, whereas as angles they are very close. This could mess up your estimates. One way round this would be, for example, to replace the heading column with two: cos(heading) and sin(heading) and to replace A with Ac and As so that the term A*heading becomes Ac*cos(heading) + As*sin(heading).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve such a system of equations is to use the: Incomplete Cholesky Conjugate Gradient Technique (ICCG). This can be implemented in Matlab, Numerical recipes in C++, Nag Fortran or many other languages. Its very efficient. Basically you are inversing a large banded matrix. The book by Golub describes it in detail.

Looks like this is useful:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

When you have more equations than unknowns, you might not have an exact solution. In such a case what you can do is use the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of your matrix A. A times b will give you the least-square distance solution. In numpy you can use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq